# How to hide/show the content of a div with dynamic height?

Tags: css

I am trying to develop a small module (like the `collapse` component of twitter bootstrap).

I don't know how to treat the content of the div which is growing up/down, it could take me many descriptions, nothing's better than an example: [Collapse deployment](http://jsfiddle.net/JjPcy/).

You can see a `div.container` which is the block destined to grow up/down.
Here i declare `height: 50px` to illustrate a state of the deployment.

Is there a way to hide the content (here a part of the text) that is out of the height of a parent div ?

I like the idea that we can access a content only by deploying another one, but i don't really don't understand how to make it happen properly in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SW86B/1/

**Updated CSS**

```
.header {
  background-color: green;
  height:20%;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease;
     -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease;
          transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

.container.open { height: 50px;}

p { margin: 0; }
```

**Use jQuery to toggle states**

```
$('button').on('click', function(event){
    $('.container').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that i understand what you are trying but you can use

```
 overflow:hidden;
```

Demo here  - http://jsfiddle.net/JjPcy/1/

Answer (score 1):

Set the `div.container`'s `overflow` css properoty to hidden.

```
div.container { overflow: hidden; }
```

Also make a class for instance called `auto-width` that has `auto` width:

```
div.auto-width { width: auto !important; }
```

Then use jQuery to toggle the class and reveal the data inside the container:

```
$('div.header button').click(function() {
    $('div.container').toggleClass('auto-width');
});
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VE9WR/3/

It could be done in so many ways. it depends on what you're looking for ;)